# RxJava Observable running in SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java

I have code which is using Observable from RxJava which is watching changes in C drive,

```
File file = new File("C:\\");
        Observable
                .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .concatMapIterable(x -> files(file))
                .distinct()
                .toBlocking()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Code prints for example new folder.

Now I want to make it run all the time when Spring-Boot application is running.
Now it works when I run it in @Test method.
I know I can do that by JavaSE or with Scheduling but I wanna make it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toBlocking operator is used to block the observer until all items are emitted, but in your example you´re subscribing so potentially you´re already waiting for all the items to be emitted.

You can still using this way but since you´re using interval which execute the pipeline async, you might want to get the result in your main thread, so you can use observerOn operator

```
Scheduler scheduler;//Main thread

Observable
                .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .concatMapIterable(x -> files(file))
                .distinct()
                .observerOn(scheduler)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

You can see some async examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

Comment: Yeah, i can try that, but how Can I make it automatically run after Spring-boot start?

Comment: Mmmmm what do you mean?. Put the code after your Spring boot initialize, and then  you will have this subscription open all the time since interval never end emitting items.

Comment: Ok i get it now

Comment: I realy want too but now its working all the time, it prints everything and I want it to print only if someone will change in structure

Comment: I think you dont understand your own pipeline here. distinct operator will filter any duplicate items emitted, but that´s it. Sorry but I cannot fix your pipeline because we dont know what you want.